# Why is this ending up as concatenation and not addition?

Tags: javascript, html

```js
function writeSum() {
  var addendOne = document.getElementById("addendOne").value; 
  var addendTwo = document.getElementById("addendTwo").value;  
  document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = addendOne + addendTwo;
  }
```

```html
<input type="number" id="addendOne"> + <input type="number" id="addendTwo"><br>
<button onclick="writeSum()">Answer</button>
<p id="sum"></p>
```

If I write 4 in the first input and 5 in the second input, I get 45. How do I change this to addition instead of concatenation.

Comment: Inputs come in as strings by default. You will need to convert to int

Comment: with `parseInt()`

Comment: with document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = +addendOne +  +addendTwo;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you are using **strings** values

for input you can use **parseInt** ... or `valueAsNumber` (only if `input[type="number"]` )

```js
function writeSum() {
  var addendOne = document.getElementById("addendOne").valueAsNumber; 
  var addendTwo = document.getElementById("addendTwo").valueAsNumber;  
  document.getElementById("sum").innerHTML = addendOne + addendTwo;
  }
```

```html
<input type="number" id="addendOne"> + <input type="number" id="addendTwo"><br>
<button onclick="writeSum()">Answer</button>
<p id="sum"></p>
```